# C++17 CRTP: using alias template from derived in base

Tags: templates, c++17, static-methods, crtp

This is for a bit of slideware, so I need to keep it simple (if I can); It is intended to demonstrate a principle (a bit of category theory), not to perform in practice.

My intent is to have an interface for `structs` with two static members

1. an alias template: `F<typename T>`
2. a member function template `fmap` which takes a function argument `Fn f` (where `Fn` is the template parameter) and returns a `std::function` value. I have a notation `Dom<Fn>` for the argument type of `f` and `Cod<Fn>` for the return type of `f`. (Implementation of `Dom` and `Cod` provided as an appendix.)

To enforce the interface, I am trying to use the CRTP because it is straightforward and easily recognised. If I can't make this work, I think SFINAE is probably going to be too much of a digression and I can get by without interface constraints.

CE link for code below: https://godbolt.org/z/Pc4Kbnchr

Here is my starting point for the interface:

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
struct Functor {
  template <typename T>
  using F = typename Derived::template F<T>;

  template <typename Fn>
  static auto fmap(Fn f) -> std::function<F<Cod<Fn>>(F<Dom<Fn>>)> {
    return Derived::fmap(f);
  }
};
```

with an example usage:

```cpp
struct Vector : public Functor<Vector> {
  template <typename T>
  using F = std::vector<T>;

  template <typename Fn>
  static auto fmap(Fn f) -> std::function<F<Cod<Fn>>(F<Dom<Fn>>)> {
    using T = Dom<Fn>;
    using U = Cod<Fn>;
    return [f](F<T> t_s) {
      F<U> u_s;
      u_s.reserve(t_s.size());

      std::transform(
          cbegin(t_s), cend(t_s), std::back_inserter(u_s), f);
      return u_s;
    };
  };
};
```

Compiling with clang++-15 produces the error:

```
error: no member named 'F' in 'Vector'
  using F = typename Derived::template F<T>;
```

I have tried many variations on my own, and ChatGPT just gets confused :) I suspect (but could easily be wrong) that the problem is

- when the compiler encounters `public Functor<Vector>`, the ISO rules require evaluating `Functor<Vector>` and performing name lookup before accounting for the body of `Vector`; or otherwise isn't allowed to consider the body of `Vector`.

Is there a simple fix, or am I just being too silly?

---

#### For those who want to test…

https://godbolt.org/z/Pc4Kbnchr

Comment: `struct Vector : public Functor<Vector> {` <--- at this point `Vector` is an incomplete type, so `Functor` cannot look inside it. BTW why would `fmap` return  a function?

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for confirming. For the chapter I'm writing, I'm constructing a category of C++ programs. A category is like a directed graph, and a functor is a function that maps from one 'graph' to another. This means mapping vertices (called objects) and the edges (called arrows), which is represented by two functions. The object function/map usually shares a name with the type constructor. The arrows (which are a subset of C++ functions) are mapped by the "function map" or `fmap`. If you're familiar with Haskell's fmap, this is the same c.f. currying.

Comment: Sorry I didn't recognise currying at first glance.

Comment: By the way member functions of Functor can look inside Vector, so you can do something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/E89a96qPa) (you can put a `static_assert` inside for better error messages).

Comment: @n.m. No problem. I suspected I was describing things that you already understood. Any suggestions for getting around this in a simple way? I don't want to change signatures too much. I just thought of perhaps having the type constructor as a parameter to functor, to which Vector passes `std::vector` during inheritance. I'll play with that. But I'll probably run into the same problem with `Derived::fmap`.

Comment: Passing std::vector also could be a solution, Or you can add [a level of indirection](https://godbolt.org/z/zfEh4qseh),

Comment: @n.m. Your linked solution is interesting. I wish I understood exactly why it worked. In the end, I have to thank you for your conversation, as it led me to the solution. It turns out that passing the type constructor to `Functor` instead of trying to fish it out of the derived class is sufficient. Here is a full working example (with Catch2 tests), with some extras thrown in, including natural transformations (which I included hoping you'd get a kick out). https://godbolt.org/z/asc94nqvx . It's certainly not how I would write production code, but it's cute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252747/discussion-between-timtro-and-n-m).